# Latest version of Firefox Portable for Mac

Tags: firefox

I would like to know what is the latest version of Firefox Portable for Mac. I just found versions from 2011-2013 and they seem pretty old. By the way, these softwares are not from the official developer (Mozilla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said there are no up-to-date Portable Firefox for OSX at the moment.

In order to have this to work, it would require to modify the source code to modifiy the directory where Firefox store it's tmp/config files.

Comment: Thanks @Matthieu Riegler - In that case, how can I install two versions of normal Firefox in my Mac?

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what Firefox Portable for Mac is, but I am running a current version of Firefox on my Macs, you can get it from here: https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=paidsearch&utm_campaign=sem2015Q2&utm_term=fast+web+browser&utm_content=speed1

Firefox discusses portable here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/973932

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but I need this program for Mac: http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable

Comment: Did you connect there with your Mac? When I do it presents me with a Mac version. In fact I downloaded Firefox 38.0.5.dmg from there a few minutes ago before I replied to you.

Comment: Yes, it can be downloaded for Mac, but I need a portable version, not the normal Firefox.

Comment: Sorry Alex,  good luck :)